# Some questions about Dirac's sea?

Tags: fermions, dirac-equation, pauli-exclusion-principle, bosons

1. Did Paul Dirac develop some way to include bosons in his formulation of the sea of particles?
2. I have read that both electrons and anti-electrons would follow the same Dirac equation. But could there be other particles, or certain situations where electrons, would follow different equations?
3. Would there be some cases where fermions would not follow Pauli's exclusion principle in the negative-energy-side?
4. Did Dirac abandon his original sea of particles formulation and follow instead other interpretations of anti-particles (like those proposed by Feynman)? Or did he pursue it until his death?

Comment: The Dirac equation has nothing to do with bosons. It describes fermions with spin 1/2.